# Using pytest_addoptions in a non-root conftest.py

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I have a project that has the following structure:

```
Project/
|
+-- src/
|   |
|   +-- proj/
|       |
|       +-- __init__.py
|       +-- code.py
|       +-- tests/
|           |
|           +-- __init__.py
|           +-- conftest.py
|           +-- test_code.py
+-- doc/
+-- pytest.ini
+-- setup.py
```

The importable package `proj` lives under the `src` directory. Tests are installed along with it, in the `proj.tests` sub-package. The code, the tests themselves, and the installation all work fine. However, I have trouble passing options to the tests.

I have an option, `--plots`, that is defined in `conftest.py` (under `Project/src/proj/tests/`), which creates a `.plots/` folder in the root folder and places some graphical debugging there:

```
# conftest.py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--plots", action="store_true", default=False)
```

There are two different ways I'd like to have to run this test:

1. The first is from the command line, in the `Project` directory:

   ```
    $ pytest --plots
   ```

   This fails immediately with

   ```
    usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
    pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --plots
      inifile: /.../Project/pytest.ini
      rootdir: /.../Project
   ```

   If I add the package directory, the run goes fine:

   ```
    $ pytest src/proj --plots
    ...
    rootdir: /.../Project, inifile: pytest.ini
    ...
   ```

   It also goes well if I specify the tests sub-directory:

   ```
    $ pytest src/proj/tests --plots
    ...
    rootdir: /.../Project, inifile: pytest.ini
    ...
   ```
2. The second way is to run the `test` function of the package itself. The `test` function is defined in `Project/src/proj/__init__.py` like this:

   ```
    # __init__.py

    def test(*args, **kwargs):
        from pytest import main
        cmd = ['--pyargs', 'proj.tests']
        cmd.extend(args)
        return main(cmd, **kwargs)
   ```

   The function is intended to be run after `Project` is installed like this:

   ```
    >>> import proj
    >>> proj.test()
   ```

   Generally, this works OK, but if I do

   ```
    >>> proj.test('--plots')
   ```

   I get the same error as usual:

   ```
    usage:  [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
    : error: unrecognized arguments: --plots
      inifile: None
      rootdir: /some/other/folder
   ```

   For this test, I ran `python setup.py develop` and then `cd`'d`to`/some/other/folder` to make sure everything installed correctly.

My goal is to have both options working correctly when I pass in the `--plots` command line option. It seems that I have found a workaround for option #1, which is to manually pass in one of the packages to `pytest`, but I don't even fully understand how that works (why can I pass in either `src/proj` or `src/proj/tests`?).

So the question is, how to I get pytest to consistently run my test package so that the correct `conftest.py` gets picked up? I am willing to consider just about any reasonable alternative that allows me to get the `--plots` option working consistently in both the source (running in a shell from `Project`) version and the `proj.test()` version.

---

For reference, here is my `pytest.ini` file:

```
# pytest.ini

[pytest]
testpaths = src/proj/tests
confcutdir = src/proj/tests
```

It doesn't appear to make any difference.

I am running with pytest 3.8.0, on Pythons 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7 (in anaconda). In all versions, the results are reproducible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quote from [the `pytest_addoption` docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_addoption):

> Note: This function should be implemented only in plugins or `conftest.py` files situated at the tests root directory due to how `pytest` [discovers plugins during startup](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#pluginorder).
>
> ...
>
> Note that `pytest` does not find `conftest.py` files in deeper nested sub directories at tool startup. It is usually a good idea to keep your `conftest.py` file in the top level test or project root directory.

When you call `pytest` from the `Project` dir, `pytest` recognizes it as the root dir, so the `addoption` hook in `Project/src/proj/tests/conftest.py` is ignored.

If the project structure you described is a requirement, I'd move the `pytest_addopts` hook impl to a separate plugin module; this can reside anywhere in the project dir, for example `Project/src/proj/tests/plugin_plots.py`. Now, if you call

```
$ pytest -p src.proj.tests.plugin_plots
```

the `addoption` hook impl will be executed and the args will be added correctly.

(you may need to adjust the `sys.path` to be able to load the custom plugin module correctly, e.g. use `PYTHONPATH=. pytest -p` or `python -m pytest -p`, or install the project in editable mode etc)

To not to enter the `-p` arg each time, persist it in `pytest.ini`, e.g.

```
# pytest.ini
[pytest]
addopts=-p src.proj.tests.plugin_plots
```

#### Edit:

When running the tests programmatically, ehnance the args list:

```
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    from pytest import main
    cmd = ['-p', 'proj.tests.plugin_plots', '--pyargs', 'proj.tests']
    cmd.extend(args)
    return main(cmd, **kwargs)
```

should work just fine.

Comment: The more I play with this, the more it answers all my questions. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help!