# How to add command-line options to pytest with a custom plugin located in a subdirectory?

Tags: python, unit-testing, plugins, pytest

Summary: my custom pytest plugin, located in a subdirectory, is imported but the implemented hook function `pytest_addoption()` is not called.

---

I have a custom pytest plugin that I want to store in its own directory, `bar/`, alongside but separate from my tests:

```
.
├── tests
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── conftest.py
│   ├── conftest.py
│   └── test_main.py
```

I invoke `pytest` in one of two ways:

From the `.` directory:

```
 $ pytest tests
```

Or from the `tests` directory:

```
 $ cd tests
 $ pytest
```

In both of these cases, pytest finds the tests in `test_main.py` and runs them.

My root-level `tests/conftest.py` sets `pytest_plugins` as per the [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/writing_plugins.html#requiring-loading-plugins-in-a-test-module-or-conftest-file):

```
# tests/conftest.py

pytest_plugins = ['bar',]

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--foo", action="store_true", help="FOO")
```

This adds the new `--foo` option, which I check with:

```
$ pytest --help | grep "foo"
  --foo                 FOO
```

I confirm that my `tests/bar/conftest.py` file is being imported:

```
$ pytest --trace-config  | grep bar
PLUGIN registered: <module 'bar' (<_frozen_importlib_external._NamespaceLoader object at 0x7f37959cb490>)>
    bar                 : None
PLUGIN registered: <module 'conftest' from '<snip>/tests/bar/conftest.py'>
```

And in that plugin I wish to register a new command-line option:

```
# tests/bar/conftest.py

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--bar", action="store_true", help="BAR")
```

But the problem is that this hook function is not being called, and the option `--bar` is *not* added:

```
$ pytest --help | egrep "foo|bar"
  --foo                 FOO
```

I've read through the PyTest documentation and I note the [pytest.hookspec.pytest_addoption](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_addoption) docs mention:

> Note: This function should be implemented only in plugins or conftest.py files situated at the tests root directory due to how pytest discovers plugins during startup.

It's not clear to me if that's a warning due to how `conftest.py` files are discovered, or an actual hard-and-fast rule making it impossible for a plugin in a subdirectory to add options to pytest even if it is imported. Implied by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52458082) S.O. answer, the explicit inclusion of the `bar` plugin via `pytest_plugins = ['bar']` might allow that hook function to be registered and thus called, unless this specific situation is not supported?

If this is not possible, is there a known workaround for implementing a custom plugin (i.e. in a separate `conftest.py` file) that can add its own command-line options?

I'm using pytest-7.2.1 with python-3.10.6.